# Truncate logging of sql queries in Django

Tags: python, django

Logging sql queries is useful for debugging but in some cases, it's useless to log the whole query, especially for big inserts. In this case, display only first N caracters would be enough.

Is there a simple way to truncate sql queries when they are logged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple actually:

in *settings.py*, let's say your logger is based on a handler which formatter is named 'simple'.

```
'formatters': {
        ...
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(message).150s'
        },
        ...
    },
```

The message will now be truncated to the first 150 caracters. Playing with handlers will allow you to specify this parameter per each logger. Thanks Python!